# Injective homomorphism between a finite group $G$ and $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem:

Given a natural number $n$, a prime number $p$ and a  finite group $G$, I need to find an injective homomorphism between $G$ and the group $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

thanks.

Comment: Such a homomorphism doesn't exist for all $n$ and $p$. Do you mean that we should choose $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** : From Cayley's theorem, we know that $G$ can be embedded inside $S_{|G|}$. So to embed $G$ inside $GL_n(\Bbb F_p)$, you have to just find an injective homomorphism from $S_{|G|}$ to $GL_n(\Bbb F_p)$. (note that this is not possible for all $n, p$)

Comment: Let $G=S_3$, $n=2$. Then $G$ can't be embedded in $S_n$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Edited.

Comment: cayley's theorem states if G is of order n then it is isomorphic to a subgroup of Sn. but G here is just finite thus its order could be a number which is not n.

Comment: Yes, @nir, in other words, there is a faithful homomorphism from $|G|$ to $S_{|G|}$.

Comment: If $|G| \leq n$, then you can embed $G$ inside $S_n$. Otherwise, it might not be possible.

Comment: i,m thinking about a permutaion as an nxn matrix obtained from the identity matrix by permutations over the rows.